# Making lines from points like Points2One for QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Previously I have been using Points2One to make lines from points in QGIS 2.18 but the plugin is not available in QGIS 3.0.

I am wondering if there is an alternative?

Comment: maybe the geoprocessing algorithm "points to path" is the one that can help you here.

Comment: QGIS 2.x already had the GRASS-tool v.to.lines, I doubt they kicked that one out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Think Points2One is the easiest way to connect points with lines but this plugin is not adopted QGIS3 yet. U can try this steps in QGIS command panel. It works for me.

**To create polygons from points,you can also use**

1) "points to path", then

2 ) "lines to polygons"

3 ) "polygons to lines"
tools without need to install any plugin.

Hope points2One plugin adopt Qqis3 quickly.

Comment: No "pointstopoat" in qgis 3

Comment: Use Progress Tools (ctrl+alt+T short key) and use search bar for points to path.  hope it is help

Comment: Not *progress* tools, but **processing** tools. `Processing` > `Toolbox`

Comment: In QGIS version 3.16 points to path method has close path check box option. You can select close path and skip other steps to make line from points.