# Transforming points in CSV to linestring / polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, points-to-line

I have `"BeginLat"`, `"BeginLon"`, `"EndLat"` and `"EndLon"` as under in a CSV-file

[image: CSV-file]

I am trying to import it as a line string but I cant. I tried to import using 
`'Create a Layer from a Delimited Text File'`, it imported the data as a point but I want as a line string instead.

[image: Result1]

So is used `'XY to Line'` but that gives me the incorrect output.

[image: XYtoLine]

Not too sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions or hints?

[image: Result2]

Comment: Have you tried something out of these threads [Draw lines from points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92751/draw-lines-from-points-in-qgis), [Making lines from points like Points2One for QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276585/making-lines-from-points-like-points2one-for-qgis-3), [Connecting points by lines using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137585/connecting-points-by-lines-using-qgis?rq=1)?

Comment: you need to arrange the start and end points, now, based on your picture 1, you have a common starting point (for example .... 10 - ... 387) and a set of end points ...

Comment: Can you try another line type `'Simple Line'`, instead of `'Geodesic'`? What will be your output then?

Comment: Those coordinates must be placed in Australia, is not it?

Comment: Are there polygons in the last screenshot, or densely packed lines? If the `XY to Line` algorithm created polygons, that would be truly bizarre behavior.

Comment: @Taras I tried Simple line but was not successful. Yes Australia

Comment: @csk they are densely packed lines. Not polygons

Comment: @Cyril I will work towards it, its a nice pointer.

Comment: Think about how to get rid of unnecessary segments...